# Why use "nohup &" rather than "exec &"

Tags: nohup, exec

I know that, `nohup` being a binary, it can be reached from any shell. But the `exec` built-in probably exists in every shell.

Is there a reason to prefer one of them, to the other?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

What's better, a fish or a bicycle? `nohup` and `exec` do different things.

`exec` replaces the shell with another program. Using `exec` in a simple background job isn't useful: `exec myprogram; more stuff` replaces the shell with `myprogram` and so doesn't run `more stuff`, unlike `myprogram; more stuff` which runs `more stuff` when `myprogram` terminates; but `exec myprogram & more stuff` starts `myprogram` in the background and then runs `more stuff`, just like `myprogram & more stuff`.

[`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) runs the specificed program with the SIGHUP signal ignored. When a terminal is closed, the kernel sends SIGHUP to the controlling process in that terminal (i.e. the shell). The shell in turn sends SIGHUP to all the jobs running in the background. Running a job with `nohup` prevents it from being killed in this way if the terminal dies (which happens e.g. if you were logged in remotely and the connection drops, or if you close your terminal emulator).

`nohup` also redirects the program's output to the file `nohup.out`. This avoids the program dying because it isn't able to write to its output or error output. Note that `nohup` doesn't redirect the input. To fully disconnect a program from the terminal where you launched it, use

```
nohup myprogram </dev/null >myprogram.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: a bicycle > a fish

Comment: I beg to differ. Fish is obviously a superior method of transportation if it can be implemented.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP But a bicycle is better food, surely?

Comment: By testing I saw that when I ran `exec firefox` and then closed `firefox`, it also closed my shell. I understood what nohup does but I don't understand what you mean when you say `exec` replaces the `shell` with the `<program>` ?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut After you run `exec firefox`, the shell is no longer running: it has been replaced by `firefox`. You can think of `exec` as combining exiting a program and starting a new one, but keeping the same process ID. The *[terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)* keeps running because nothing told it to stop. When you later exit Firefox, the `firefox` process terminates. The terminal notices that its child process has exited and so it exits in turn.

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Give a man a bicycle and he can ride it to the supermarket and buy fish for a lifetime.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `</dev/null` input redirection? Would stdin otherwise somehow be "left hanging" when the shell closes?

Comment: @shadowtalker This is about the terminal, not the shell. If the program tries to read from its standard input and fails because the terminal has gone away, it might decide to terminate prematurely. `nohup` only prevents the automatic SIGHUP, not a decision by the program. Some implementations of `nohup` actually redirect stdin to `/dev/null`, but not all.

Answer (score 22):

`exec &` => executes a process as a background process so you may continue using the same terminal for other jobs.

`nohup` => avoids all SIGHUP(terminate signal) and continues execution even if you terminal is closed.

`exec` process dies when a `SIGHUP` is received, but `nohup` process continues.

Comment: This answer appears to be correct.  As other answers above say, normally `exec` replaces the running process, but that doesn't seem to happen when you use `&` to background the exec'd command.  Neither in bash nor zsh.

Comment: @DanPritts What do you mean with it does not happen? A background subprocess gets started and then replaced, so `exec smth &` is the same as `(exec smth) &`, isn't that what's happening?

Comment: I mean it doesn't get exec'd in the sense that you would normally think of (replacing the current running shell) - it just gets run as a background process.  I guess it probably is the same as `(exec smth) &`.  But I wouldn't expect it to be the same - I would expect it to be a syntax error, how can you exec a process (replacing yourself) and then background the exec'd process?  You're not there to do it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare `nohup` with `exec`. When you run an executable with `nohup`, the process won't be killed when you logout (ssh session); usually `nohup` is used with `nice` to run processes on a lower priority. The `HUP` signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout

Answer (score 2):

The shell built in command `exec <command>` replaces the shell with `<command>`, no new process, no new PID is created. After completion of `<command>` normally your terminal will close. By running it in the background first a subshell is created, which then similarly is immediately replaced by `<command>`.

The `nohup <command>`  command will run `<command>` but immume to hangups  (kill -s 1) so it will not be terminated when the shell, the terminal from which it was started is, is closed. By running it in the background first a subshell is created and the command runs in the background, returning you to the prompt.

In scripting the immediate effect is more or less the same though, `<command>` is started by your script and the script will continue without waiting for `<command>` to start, to send output or to complete.

Comment: I too am not sure about what exec does. I mean… I understand what it’s supposed to do but I can see only a minor difference between doing `script.sh &` or `exec script.sh &`. In both case the command is executed in a child process, it doesn’t replace the calling process, see: http://paste.alacon.org/44474 (too long to copy it here in a comment…).

What am I doing wrong?