# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

Tags: bash, nohup

I ran the following command

```
nohup conda activate shuffle_pair_end_reads && python3 shuffle_pair_end_reads.py \
    fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R1.fq.gz \
    fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R2.fq.gz \
    >fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merged_R1_R2.fa \
    2>merged_R1_R2.log &
```

but unfortunately, I got this after I pressed the second time enter

```
 nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

[1]+  Exit 1                  nohup conda activate shuffle_pair_end_reads && python3 shuffle_pair_end_reads.py fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R1.fq.gz fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R2.fq.gz > fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merged_R1_R2.fa 2> merged_R1_R2.log
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You should at least know that the command after `&&` has nothing to do with `nohup` and `nohup` knows nothing about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ type -a nohup
nohup is /usr/bin/nohup
```

Nohup is not part of the shell syntax. It is just an executable, which means you cannot just type arbitrary command and prefix it with `nohup` to expect it to be executed with SIGHUP ignored. In the case of

```
nohup conda activate shuffle_pair_end_reads && python3 shuffle_pair_end_reads.py \
    fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R1.fq.gz \
    fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merge_R2.fq.gz \
    >fastp-filtered-merged4racon/merged_R1_R2.fa \
    2>merged_R1_R2.log &
```

`nohup` is executed with the arguments `conda`, `activate` and `shuffle_pair_end_reads`. Everything after the first `&&` is another simple command. `nohup` knows nothing about it and cannot control the behavior of it.

As it is written, it means executing `conda activate shuffle_pair_end_reads` with `SIGHUP` ignored, then if `nohup` succeeds, process to the python script.

As for the redirection of stdin and stdout, the man page has stated clearly about it.

> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null. If
>   standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if
>   possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise. If standard error is a
>   terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use
>   'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

In your case, the input of your command is not redirected, so `nohup` redirects it for you from `/dev/null`. Similarly, `nohup` redirects the standard output to `nohup.out` for you, issuing a warning (note this is just a warning) "ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'" and writing the warning to stderr.

As for the exit status of `nohup`, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650307/how-to-get-the-proper-exit-code-from-nohup) explains it well. You need to check by yourself why the command `nohup conda activate shuffle_end_reads` is issuing an exit status of `1`.

Using `nohup` as though it were part of the `bash` syntax can lead to funny errors. One of the simplest,

```
nohup cd myfolder && ./script.sh &
```

will fail with the following message written to stderr:

> nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
>
> nohup: failed to run command 'cd': No such file or directory

The first line is just a warning. The second line explains the error. `nohup` just tries to invoke its `$1` as an executable and `cd` is never a standalone executable.

When I need to combine multiple commands for `nohup`, I usually use the syntax

```
nohup bash -c "long command" &
```

There may be better ways but that's what I use. In the example above, if there is really a reason that you cannot `cd` before `nohup`, I will do

```
nohup bash -c "cd myfolder && ./script.sh` &
```

One last thing to keep in mind is that your program may install its own signal handlers that makes `nohup` useless. As shown in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446625/why-nohup-background-process-is-getting-killed).