# Script called with nohup dies sometimes when calling script exits

Tags: nohup

I wrote a little bash script showing a screenshot menu (`screenshot-menu.bash`):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'Select an option:

s whole screen
w active window
r select region
'
read -rsn1 key
sleep 0.1

case $key in
  s|w|r) nohup ./screenshot.bash -$key & ;;
  *) echo Canceled. >> ./log.txt ;;
esac
```

This script runs `nohup ./screenshot.bash` with a parameter. This is `screenshot.bash`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [[ "$#" > 0 ]]; do case $1 in
  -s|--screen) PARAM=''; TYPE='Screen'; shift;;
  -w|--window) PARAM='-u'; TYPE='Window'; shift;;
  -r|--region) PARAM='-s'; TYPE='Region'; shift;;
  *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; exit 1; shift; shift;;
esac; done

sleep 0.2
scrot $PARAM $(xdg-user-dir PICTURES)/'%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S $wx$h '$TYPE.png -e 'echo "$f" && notify-send -u low "$f"'
```

When I run `./screenshot-menu.bash` inside a terminal, then enter `r`, everything works fine: I can select a region and I get a screenshot of that region.

But I want to be able to call this script from everywhere. That's why I have a keybinding that runs this script in a new terminal window:

```bsh
alacritty -t "Screenshot menu" -o "window.dimensions.columns=20" -o "window.dimensions.lines=7" -e ~/bin/screenshot-menu.bash
```

(Or simpler `gnome-terminal -- ~/bin/screenshot.bash`.)

That's the reason I use `nohup`. I want the terminal to exit because I don't want to have it in the screenshot. But of course, `screenshot.bash` must not die.

The second method (script in a new terminal window) works maybe once in five times. The other times, the cursor doesn't turn into a cross-hair for selecting a region. I suppose, `screenshot.bash` dies although I use `nohup`.

What could be causing this random behavior?

Comment: Based on a bit of testing, I'd guess the shell that runs `screenshot-menu.bash` gets a `SIGHUP` and exits before `nohup ./screenshot.bash` can actually run. You may be able to confirm this by adding a short `sleep` at the end of `screenshot-menu.bash`. I'm not saying this would be a good solution, though; there likely is a better approach.

Comment: ...sorry, I meant "the process forked off `screenshot-menu.bash`" in place of "the shell that runs `screenshot-menu.bash`".

Comment: I'd way you're running into a race condition. Why do you have the `sleep` calls?

Comment: @fra-san: `sleep 0.1` at the end seems to fix it! I tried it five times and it worked every time. Thank a lot!

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: There is a sleep because otherwise the keyup event of the selection (for example key `r`) cancels `scrot` immediately. I added a second sleep when I split this script into two because I wanted to make sure, the terminal closes before the screenshot is taken. But one `sleep` only in `screenshot.bash` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that the process forked by `screenshot-menu.bash` to execute `nohup ./screenshot.bash -$key` in the background receives a `SIGHUP` and exits before `nohup` can run.

A simple experiment seems to confirm this:

```bsh
$ alacritty -e sh -c 'nohup sleep 1000 &'
$ pgrep -a sleep
$
```

`strace`ing the whole command shows that `sh` forks, but there is no `execve` running `nohup` before the forked process receives a `SIGHUP` — when `alacritty` terminates and the pseudo-terminal it created disappears — and exits.

Without looking for alternative approaches (which likely exist when it comes to mixing terminal and graphical applications), a logical solution is to avoid applying `nohup` to the command that is going to the background and use it on the parent process instead. For instance:

```bsh
$ alacritty -e sh -c 'nohup sh -c "sleep 1000 &"'
$ pgrep -a sleep
625910 sleep 1000
```

In `screenshot-menu.bash` you may thus change this line

```bsh
s|w|r) nohup ./screenshot.bash -$key & ;;
```

into

```bsh
s|w|r) nohup sh -c "./screenshot.bash \"-$key\" &" ;;
```

Alternatively, you may enable job control in `screenshot-menu.bash` with `set -m` and get rid of `nohup` (the shell will then start background pipelines (a simple command is a pipeline, too) in their own process groups, and only the foreground process group is delivered a `SIGHUP` when its controlling terminal disappears), provided you are fine with ensuring that nothing in `screenshot.bash` tries to read from or write to the terminal (i.e. you need explicit redirections equivalent to those performed by `nohup`).

For instance, `screenshot-menu.bash` may become:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m

echo 'Select an option:
...
'

case $key in
  s|w|r) </dev/null >>./log.txt 2>&1 ./screenshot.bash "-$key" & ;;
  *) echo Canceled. >>./log.txt ;;
esac
```

See also:

- [Process killed before being launched in background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/480934/315749) - a really similar question; more words of explanation and interesting solutions in the answers;
- [Is it safe to use & and output redirection instead of nohup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379118/315749) - on how my alternative based on job control is not equivalent to `nohup`.